# How Can I Align my Content in Right side of DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

One of the column in my DataGrid is

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="m_gridControl">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="columnCategory" Width="10*">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="myStackPanel">
                     <TextBlock>Category</TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CategoryChooser"></ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I am unable locate my Combobox in the right side of the DataDridTextColumn.

I tried following

1. Attached Horizontal Alignment = Right on Combobox
2. Attached Flow Direction = Right to Left in StackPanel
3. Created a Static resource as converter to set Left Margin to Combo box.

None of the worked unfortunately.
Can you guys Help me out?
Even during Resizing of columns width also my combobox should always fall towards right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the `ComboBox` + `TextBlock` to be right aligned? If so I believe you can do something along these lines:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="m_gridControl">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="columnCategory" Width="10*">
            <!-- Additional Style -->
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <!---------------------->
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="myStackPanel">
                    <TextBlock>Category</TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CategoryChooser"></ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you want the `TextBlock` to stay in one place, and the `ComboBox` to be right aligned, it will require a bit more manipulation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris,
But i want the TextBlock to stay in one place, and the ComboBox to be right aligned

Comment: Ah, you probably don't want to accept this as an answer just yet, someone might have the perfect solution =D I'll try and have another look later.